# C Convert char* to uint8_t []

Tags: c, type-conversion

I'm working on a program that receives an encrypted string. For this I'm using [tiny-AES-c](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) library.

The encrypted string I'm receiving is `char*`. In order to use the string with the function `AES_CBC_decrypt_buffer(struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf,  uint32_t length)` I will need to convert the string to `uint8_t []`.

This is how the *tiny-AES-c* library likes the format, as seen in their [test.c](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c/blob/master/test.c#L146):

```
uint8_t in[]  = { 0x6b, 0xc1, 0xbe, 0xe2, 0x2e, 0x40, 0x9f, 0x96, 0xe9, 0x3d, 0x7e, 0x11, 0x73, 0x93, 0x17, 0x2a };
```

I've been told this can be achieved using [strtoul](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtoul.htm). I've researched this function quite a bit but can't seem to find any questions/documentation/examples related to the issue I'm having.

My question being, how can I convert the contents of a `char*` to an `uint8_t []` array, in the format like the snippet above?

Comment: In C this is done for you, arrays decay into pointers, unless you're doing something really strange. Where's the call you need to make that isn't working? `strtoul` is **not** the answer here.

Comment: Simply use a cast...

Comment: @tadman Do you mean `in[]` will be changed to a pointer anyway, meaning I can just do something like `uint8_t in[] = "This is my text";`?

Comment: Just declare it as a pointer in the first place, forget the `[]` nonsense. `char*` is just a generic "character buffer" anyway.

Comment: What makes you think that you need to convert to `uint8_t []` in the first place? I would correct that misunderstanding before you go any further.

Comment: Also, I know it's not your code, but that prototype would be better written as `AES_CBC_decrypt_buffer(struct AES_ctx* ctx, void* buf, size_t length)`. Then you wouldn't be asking about `uint8_t`at all.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Hello Jonathon, I wish I knew. I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of days now because of the uint8_t - also to answer your other question about converting to uint8_t; likely a rookie mistake on my end as I saw the argument needed to be uint8_t and my data was char*. I didn't know I could cast it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be as simple as:

```
char* buf = "test";
size_t length = 5;

AES_CBC_decrypt_buffer(ctx, (uint8_t*) buf,  (uint32_t) length)
```

`uint8_t` and `char` are largely the same thing for binary data, same as `size_t` and `uint32_t` are compatible for values under 2^32.

C99 code that uses the [integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) will use things like `uint8_t`, but older C code, or code with no C99 dependency, will use `char`. They basically mean the same thing.

Comment: That helps, please allow me some time to figure out the implementation

Comment: Well, *unsigned* char is the old uint8_t equivalent.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica True, to be more technical.

Comment: In the end the sign is only important if you convert the (unsigned or not) chars to larger integers.